# How to force a test to fail with selenium and python?

Tags: python, selenium, assert

I was searching for a way to do this a lot of times but I didn't find any solution.

I'll show you what I mean:

```
 def test_288_try_this(self):
    try:
        do_something()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        self.assertTrue(False, "This test fails bigger than you.")
```

I'm doing it that way, Of course is working buy I feel is not the correct way. I'd like to know if there is any kind of "self.assertFail(fail_message)" or some like that.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try understanding this answer and comments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71215136/protractor-not-failing-current-spec-after-expected-condition-error/71216336#71216336

Answer (score -1):

Python:
If you want to verify whether the particular web element is present on a page after navigation. You can use the below method.
self.assertTrue(element, msg='Element name is not present after naviagting to x page')

Comment: Is not always about if an element exists, NoSuchElementException is an example.